# Feasibility: Pointcloud-Mesh Registration to determine unknown transforms?

Tags: slam, mapping, localization, pointcloud, pose

**Hello friends,**

I have a series of timestamped 2D laserscan cross sections from a mobile robot driving from one end of a straight pipe to another. The robot travels roughly around the same speed, but not necessarily in a straight line. I do not have odometry, imu, or any other sensor data, but I DO have a reasonably accurate design stl/mesh of the pipe. Using this, I'd like to estimate the robot's pose history in the pipe frame (and thereby estimating the true transforms between scan frames).

The pipe itself has sections of tapering geometry and distinct features present in both the laserscan data and the model. My initial idea was to assume a constant speed (from travel time and pipe length), batch small samples of scans around a single pose frame for individual sections along the pipe, and create a set of pose-anchored sectional pointclouds. I'd then somehow perform registration of these pointclouds to the mesh to roughly estimate the pipe-frame transformation.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is this a bad approach? Is there an easier and more accurate method I can use?
2. Is it even possible to create a useful point representation of the mesh? (to use with something like ICP)?

**Appreciate any advice or help on this, thank you! :3**